# How would I use text to show more text in a different location on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I been researching around looking for how to use  tags and javascript to create an area where more information can be seen pertaining to that text you would click on? An excellent example of coding that was given to me, but I already have a layout where the text are set inside div tags.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have an `onclick` that toggles the `display` value of another div:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuw8u/)

**CSS**

```
#toggle {
   position: absolute;
   left: 20px;
   top: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="toggle">
   Show More
</div>
<div id="showMoreText" style="display: none">
   more text here
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = showMore;
}

function showMore() {
    var div = document.getElementById('showMoreText');
    var display = div.style.display;
    display == "none" ? div.style.display = "block" : div.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Is there a place where I can play the location of the "more text here" into the code such as x-pixels and y-pixels on the page?

Comment: Sure just set `position` to `absolute` then adjust the `left` and `top` values. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: How do you make it so that the "Show me More" text comes before the "more text" with more information shows up? Also, How do you go upon changing the location of the "more" text to a different spot on the page besides the link you are clicking?